# Call excel VBA module with variable change

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to use the code below in multiple areas within my `excel VBA`, however there must be some changes to the variables within the code to make it specific to that area. E.g.,

```
Dim XXXcountcurrent As Long

' Delete the items containing the word XXX in Material current
    Sheets("Materials Current").Select
    Range("A2:C" & Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    If XXXcountcurrent <> 0 Then
    Selection.Rows.Delete
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$C").AutoFilter Field:=2

'Paste XXX total in workings sheet
    Sheets("Workings").Select
    rcell.Offset(?) = XXXcountcurrent
```

The code above is a small section taken from the `VBA`. The XXX indicated refers to different scenarios, e.g., it could refer to `"knife"`, `"handle"` etc. In addition, I would like the offset cell to be adjusted in the code indicated by? (I am unassuming this must be variable as well).

I do not want to repeat the code when there are only small changes to be made. Can someone please assist?

Comment: Make sure you enter 4 spaces before each line of code, this will keep it formatted and easy to read on here. Easiest way to do it is highlight all the code in the VBE then press TAB once then copy and paste straight in here.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of options, I would most likely have this repeatable code in a sub routine with variables to be populated upon calling.

Here is an example of how to do this in a very basic format:

```
Sub TestCallingSubs()
    CallingSubs "Hello"
    CallingSubs "World"
    CallingSubs "!!!!!"
End Sub

Sub CallingSubs(MyString As String)
    MsgBox MyString
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in subroutine, such as:

```
Sub DoSomething(ByVal xxx As String, ByVal myOffset As Long)
    'here's your code
End Sub
```

Then call it this way:

```
Sub Whatever
   DoSomething "John Doe", 0
End Sub
```

Comment: In the event that I want to filter the XXX (contains), how will I go about coding. Currently I have "rngcurrent.AutoFilter Field:=FilterField, Criteria1:=Array( _ =*xxx*), Operator:=xlFilterValues". Thank you

Comment: Thank you for the quick response,I have now followed your advice as mentioned above. However,I would like the xxx to refer to knife,etc.I have a table with data and would like to filter the word knife using the code below. Normally I would state the last line of code below and specify the word, e.g., "=*Knife*". My question is how would I do this using a sub as proposed above as I get a ByRef argument type mismatch. 
     'Filter for item
    rngcurrent.AutoFilter Field:=FilterField, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "=*item*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

Comment: I changed my answer. Please, look at it.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the "ByRef argument type mismatch" error. However I now get an error when I use the sub. Please see sub code below, do you have any advice? "Sub generic_item_quantity(ByVal new_sheet As String, ByVal old_sheet As String, ByVal sheet_test As String, ByVal item As String, ByVal location As Long, ByVal rngcurrent As Range, ByVal countcurrent As Long" Then when I call the sub "generic_item_quantity "Pumps current", "Pumps Previous", "Pumps Test", "Pump", 5, rngpumpcurrent, countpumpcurrent" The error I am getting is Runtime error 424, Object required.

Comment: I cannot chat as apparently I need 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk.

Comment: OK, go to my profile page. There you'll find a link to my site (follow them). On the main page you'll find "email" button. Write an email to me and add sample Excel file. I'll promise to look at this file and i'll reply to you ASAP.

Comment: I have already asked another question. Apologies. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30931093/calling-generic-sub-in-excel-with-changes-to-variables-in-string-long-an-range